# latex ambiguous warning while compiling with MikTex

Tags: latex, warnings, ambiguous, miktex

I'm compiling LaTeX with MiKTeX. I get an ambiguous warning which interrupts compilation.

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \' invalid in math mode on input line 209.

209 > \begin{equation} M = \left\{ m : {R_n} \left[ a \right] \right\} \end{equation}
```

The same line compiles very well on Overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try replacing `\{` and `\}` in this instance with `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` - this should compile properly. So your equation becomes

```
M = \left\lbrace m : {R_n} \left[ a \right] \right\rbrace
```